# Space Complexity of Recursive Binary Search

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search

What will be the space complexity Of Recursive Binary Search?

Answer (score 1):

Binary search requires three variables. So the space is constant. O(1)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Space_complexity

Comment: A naive implementation might duplicate these values in each call, pushing it to `O(log length)`